# input type submit value gets affected with css transform property

Tags: html, css

I am using an input type submit tag in my website. Its value attribute has "submit" text. The issue I am facing is that when I apply text transform property to input tag, the text gets italicize too. I did a little search on internet but couldn't find any luck so far. I have pasted the markup and style below.

```css
#submit-button input[type=submit] {
background: #093f7d !important;
color: white !important;
-webkit-transform: skew(160deg);
-moz-transform: skew(160deg);
-o-transform: skew(160deg);
width: 19%;
font-size: 18px;

}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
```

Comment: `when I apply text transform property to input tag, the text gets italicize too` --> and what have this to do with the transform? and both are logical, you expect what ?

Comment: I'm assuming he doesn't want the text skewed, only the button. There are many ways to achieve this

Comment: @JordanQuartermain yes you are right. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a button and not an input. Place a span element inside the button and reverse-skew the span. I think this is your desired behaviour.

```css
button {
background: #093f7d !important;
color: white !important;
transform: skew(160deg);
width: 19%;
font-size: 18px;
}

button span {
transform: skew(20deg);
display: block;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit"><span>Submit</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a button instead of input type and use a  o  for the button text. Skew the button and unskew the text.

```css
#btn {
background: #093f7d !important;
color: white !important;
-webkit-transform: skew(160deg);
-moz-transform: skew(160deg);
-o-transform: skew(160deg);
width: 19%;
font-size: 18px;
}

#btn-text {
    -ms-transform: skewX(-160deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-160deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(-160deg);
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn"><div id="btn-text">Submit</div></button>
```